# Unsupported JNI version detected in LWJGL

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lwjgl

So I tried using glfw and opengl for game development in java (for some reason) and recently I start getting an lwjgl error that I still don't know how to fix it

here is my source code:

```
import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.system.*;

import java.nio.*;
import java.util.Objects;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

public class main {

    private long window;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + Version.getVersion() + "!");

        init();
        loop();

        glfwFreeCallbacks(window);
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        glfwTerminate();
        Objects.requireNonNull(glfwSetErrorCallback(null)).free();
    }

    private void init() {
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

        if ( !glfwInit() ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
        }

        glfwDefaultWindowHints();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);

        int windowWidth = 640;
        int windowHeight = 480;

        window = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "Game", GLFW_RESIZABLE, NULL);

        if ( window == NULL )
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
            if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS )
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
        });

        try ( MemoryStack stack = stackPush() ) {
            IntBuffer pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*
            IntBuffer pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*

            glfwGetWindowSize(window, pWidth, pHeight);

            GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
            assert vidmode != null;
            glfwSetWindowPos(
                    window,
                    (vidmode.width() - pWidth.get(0)) / 2,
                    (vidmode.height() - pHeight.get(0)) / 2
            );
        }

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        glfwShowWindow(window);
    }

    private void loop() {
        GL.createCapabilities();

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose(window) ) {
            glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
            glEnd();

            glfwSwapBuffers(window);

            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new main().run();
    }

}
```

(If there are improvement I could use in the code the pls tell me)

And here is the error:

```
Hello LWJGL 3.3.1 build 7!
[LWJGL] [ThreadLocalUtil] Unsupported JNI version detected, this may result in a crash. Please inform LWJGL developers.
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffc3c5aba56, pid=6740, tid=14624
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (19.0.1+10) (build 19.0.1+10-21)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x3ba56]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\IntelliJ IDEA Projects\Game Project\hs_err_pid6740.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

Process finished with exit code 1
```

IDE: IntelliJ IDEA community

LWJGL 3.3.1 build 7

I tried changing JDK version, changing SDK version, redownloading LWJGL libraries, editing source codes

(None of it worked)

Comment: LWJGL 3.3.1 **doesn't** support to Java 19. Also, I see `glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "Game", GLFW_RESIZABLE, NULL)` in your code. This is invalid.

Comment: when I switch to jvm-17, in my case, the error message above disappears. See also https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/7019

Answer (score 0):

The 4th parameter in `glfwCreateWindow` accepts a pointer of monitor.

Simply replace it with `NULL`.

```java
window = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "Game", NULL, NULL);
```